# HIding the Next button with a Custom Action in MSI Installer

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer, installshield, custom-action

I am trying to hide or disable the next button from within a custom action. I've searched around for possible ways to do it but all i found was to set a variable in my custom action and set the next button to enable when this variable is equal to a value. 
I have now found tutorials on hiding the cancel button. I wonder if this same method could be used for the Next button (or any other field for that matter!) but I just don't understand two functions in it.
these are MsiCreateRecord() and MsiRecordSetInteger().
Can anyone offer an explanation as to where the link between creating a record with a set number of field, and using this record to hide the Cancel button?

Here is the function from the microsoft website which uses it.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>
#include <msi.h>
#include <Msiquery.h>

UINT __stdcall HideCancelButton(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    PMSIHANDLE hRecord = MsiCreateRecord(2);
    if ( !hRecord)
       return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;

   if (ERROR_SUCCESS != MsiRecordSetInteger(hRecord, 1, 2)
    || ERROR_SUCCESS != MsiRecordSetInteger(hRecord, 2, 0))
       return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;

   MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA, hRecord);

   return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done through [control conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here are some articles which may help you:

- http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-user-interface/conditionally-enable-disable-installer-control/
- http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-user-interface/conditionally-enable-disable-control-part-2/

Basically, you control the button visibility through an installer property. From your custom action you can set that property with [MsiSetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: It's worth noting that setting properties through MsiSetProperty does not trigger a re-evaluation of control conditions. One way to work around this is to have another set-property action triggered off the same control event set the property (again, or from a temporary).

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of making a square peg to fit in the square hole. MsiProcessMessage is the means by which you can communicate with the Msi's UI and tell it to do things. Such as hide the cancel button. But to do that, you have to send it a message in the way it expects, which includes a Record. You create and populate it with the calls mentioned.

It's hard to decipher the way they describe the fields, but the values for the record are all documented on [MsiProcessMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370354.aspx).

Edit: No, you cannot use this method to affect the Next button. This method using MsiProcessMessage is targeted primarily for supporting cases in the built-in basic UI, where there is *only* a cancel button.

Comment: If it was me, I assume I'd just set a property like HIDEBUTTON=1 and use that in a set of mutually exclusive ControlEvents to make the button visible or not.   Am I missing something?

Comment: Oops, I meant Control Condition. :-)

Comment: And just how do you set up that control condition for the basic UI? Oh, my mistake on this not being what the question was really asking; I missed that part about the Next button.